# TitleBar seticon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, winui-3

Why WinUI3 MyAppWindow.SetIcon("Images/MyIcon.ico") works if I compile locally with Visual Studio 2022,
but if I create the package for the store and download the app, MyAppWindow.SetIcon doesn't work ?
Am I doing something wrong?

MyAppWindow.Title = MyString;
MyAppWindow.SetIcon("Images/MyIcon.ico");

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [AppWindow APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/windowing/windowing-overview) to change the title bar icon for the packaged winui 3.0 app.

I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1914